# How can I whitelist a font provider for Google AMP pages?

Tags: caching, cdn, amp-html

The AMP documentation states:

> Font providers can be whitelisted if they support CSS-only
>   integrations and serve over HTTPS. The following origins are currently
>   allowed for font serving via link tags:
>
> https://fast.fonts.net 
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com
>
> IMPLEMENTERS NOTE: Adding to this list requires a change to the Google
>   AMP Cache CSP rule.

So how can I add typography.com hosted fonts to the "AMP Cache CSP rule" as indicated by the "IMPLEMENTER'S NOTE?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fast.fonts.net was whitelisted in an [issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/709) on the @ampproject/amphtml GitHub project. I would assume additional font providers would follow the same process. Be sure to read the [contributing guide](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) before opening any issues.